# why i can't change a public variable of a class in the main function

Tags: c++, xcode

[at line 14th where f().i = 10,the Xcode said Expression is not assignable,why?Is it illegal?]

```
class A{
public:
    int i;
    A():i(0){}
};

A f()
{
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    f().i = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`f()` produces a temporary. C++ doesn't allow assigning to a member of a temporary. [Formally](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators), `f().i` is an [*xvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), while assignment requires an *lvalue*.

Such an assignment would be rather pointless anyway, as the temporary would get destroyed very soon afterwards.

Comment: int main() {
        A b;
        f() = b;
        return 0;
    }
how about this?
why f() = b is legal?
thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, it's OK to call methods on temporaries, including non-const methods. `f() = b;` is a shorthand for `f().operator=(b)`, calling implicitly defined `operator=`